# Rails User>Team>Members

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, belongs-to

I'm new to Rails, and I'm trying to build this in my app:

Signed Captain creates a Team (name, color, etc) then add Members in it. Members are automatically assigned to the Team created.

My signed Captain has a button to create a new Team on his profile, it goes to the team#new view.
Once the team form is validated, the member#new is loaded to add members one by one to the team.

I set up the models relationships :

```
Captain:
has_many :teams
has_many :members through :team

Team: 
belongs_to :captain #captain_id
has_many :members

Member:
belongs_to :team #team_id
has_one :captain
```

I found how to add the captain_id inside the team table using devise and current_user, but I just can't figure out how to deal with the team_id once the team created. I would like to get the team_id value in the "add member" view and deal with my Member controller to save it with each member.

Comment: Can you post your routes for teams and members? You could use `resources :teams do resources :members end`. Then you'd use `params[:id]` when browsing a team and `params[:team_id]` when you're looking at a team member.

Comment: Hello Nathan, thank you for yoour fast answer.
Since i used scaffold to generate teams & members, my routes are quite empty.

  resources :members

  resources :teams
 devise_for :captains, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations/registrations" }

Comment: Just in case you didn't know, you can use [**markdown**](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to format code snippets in the body of your post. This helps make your question/answer more concise and readable.

Comment: Just added them. Thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

If you structure your routes in the following fashion you'll have access to the team and member details on member pages as well as a team id on the team pages:

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :teams do
  resources :members
end

# uncomment to have members viewable when not associate with a team in the url
# resources :members
```

You can route to a team using named routes: `teams_path`, `team_path(@team)`
And for members: `team_members_path(@team)`, `team_member_path(@team, @member)`

In the teams_controller you'll have access to `params[:id]` when a team id is provided. For instance, in the url `/teams/1`, `params[:id]` would hold the value `1`.

In the members controller, you'll have `params[:team_id]` and `params[:id]` will hold the member id.

For example:

```
# app/controllers/teams_controller.rb
def show
  @team = Team.find params[:id]
end

# app/controllers/members_controller.rb
def index
  # finds the team and pre-loads members in the same query
  @team = Team.includes(:members).find(params[:team_id])
end

# /teams/1/members/2
def show
  @member = Member.find params[:id]
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much Nathan, that's very helpful.
I set up the resources as you suggested it.
I think I understand the principle of the params[:id] better.
I'm trying to add properly the new attribute team_id inside my member controller when creating it. Do I have to get rid of the "members_params?
@member = member.new(members_params)

Comment: `members_params` specifies which attributes you are expecting to be sent (and will usually be used when mass-assigning attributes for new or update calls). Do member assignment like you have, then you can assign `@member.team_id = params[:team_id]` or you can include (and permit) team_id to be passed as part of the member params.

Comment: Everything seems to work now, so Thank you for all your help !

I have few theorical questions regarding the nested resources:
- Since I have my nest relation between team and member, why do I have to precise the @member.team_id = params[:team_id] manually when creating a new member (member#create) ?

Comment: You could alternatively include :team_id as either a hidden or select menu in your member form and permit setting :team_id in your member_params method. Either will work. The association you have is more for browsing resources. The models themselves have no knowledge of how they're being accessed. HTH

Answer (score 0):

So we have a Card which contains multiple teammates

Using nested resources:

routes.rb :

```
resources :cards do 
resources :teammates 
end
```

teammate new view

```
<%= form_for [@card,@teammate] do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

Teammate controller

```
  def index
    @card = Card.includes(:teammates).find(params[:card_id])
    @teammates = Teammate.all
  end

  # GET /teammates/1
  # GET /teammates/1.json
  def show
    @teammate = Teammate.find(params[:id])
  end

  # GET /teammates/new
  def new
    @card = Card.find(params[:card_id])
    @teammate = Teammate.new
  end

  # GET /teammates/1/edit
  def edit
    @teammate = Teammate.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /teammates
  # POST /teammates.json
  def create
    @card = Card.find(params[:card_id])
    @teammate = Teammate.new(teammate_params)
    @teammate.card_id = params[:card_id]
    respond_to do |format|
      if @teammate.save
        format.html { redirect_to @teammate, notice: 'Teammate was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @teammate }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @teammate.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I tried to put a before filter in members controller :
before_filter :require_card
private
def require_card
  @teammate = Teammate.find(params[:id])
end

But it brings me errors so I just abandonned it

If proper ways exist to do the trick / improve my learning, I would love to know them so feel free to give me clues.

Thank you !

Comment: This is a separate question. You could post this by itself rather than an answer to the above unrelated question... Naming-wise, I'd name the before filter after what you're retrieving, like `find_teammate` or `find_card`. That and you'll probably only want to run the before_filter when specific actions are requested. `before_filter :find_card, only: [:index,:show]` or something similar.